# Long Thread & EDT

Tags: java, thread-safety, swing

I’m trying to make a simple gui app that starts a “long” process that can be started and stopped. The process generates random numbers and displays them in a JList. As numbers are being displayed (i.e. process is started), user can select a number from JList and delete. 
[gui and uml http://mypages.valdosta.edu/dgibson/courses/cs4322/post.jpg](http://mypages.valdosta.edu/dgibson/courses/cs4322/post.jpg)

I'm interested to know what improvements I could make to my approach. (And yes, I need to read TrashGod's posts on EDT and SwingWorker, I will!)

```
public class MVC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                create();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void create() {
        RandomNumberModel model = new RandomNumberModel();
        Controller controller = new Controller(model);
        View view = new View(controller);
        controller.setView(view);

        JFrame f = new JFrame("EDT & Long Thread");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(view);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

public class View extends JPanel {
    JList list;
    DefaultListModel<Double> listModel;
    JTextArea area;
    JTextField field;
    JButton btnGenerate = new JButton("Start Generation");
    JButton btnStop = new JButton("Stop Generation");
    JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete selected");
    Controller controller;

    public View(Controller controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
        this.setSize(new Dimension(600, 300));

        // Create GUI components
        listModel = new DefaultListModel<Double>();
        list = new JList(listModel);
        area = new JTextArea();
        btnStop.setEnabled(false);

        btnGenerate.addActionListener(controller);
        btnStop.addActionListener(controller);
        btnDelete.addActionListener(controller);

        // Assemble GUI components
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(btnGenerate);
        buttonPanel.add(btnStop);

        JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
        listPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        listPanel.add(new JScrollPane(list));
        listPanel.add(btnDelete, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(listPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.add(new JScrollPane(area));
    }
}

public class Controller implements ActionListener {
    static class ControlException extends Exception {}
    static class StopGenException extends ControlException {}

    View view;
    RandomNumberModel model;
    Thread thread = null;
    volatile boolean isStopGen = false;

    public Controller(RandomNumberModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public void setView(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            if (view.btnGenerate.getActionCommand().equals(
                    e.getActionCommand())) {
                view.listModel.clear();
                startNumGen();
            } else if (view.btnStop.getActionCommand().equals(
                    e.getActionCommand())) {
                stopNumGen();
            } else if (view.btnDelete.getActionCommand().equals(
                    e.getActionCommand())) {
                deleteElement();
            }
        } 
        catch (ControlException exc) {
            System.out.println(exc);
        }
    }

    public void startNumGen() throws ControlException {

        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    doGeneration();
                }
                catch (ControlException exc) {
                    System.out.println("Stopped " + exc);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                    System.out.println("Interrupted " + exc);
                } 

                finally {
                    view.btnGenerate.setEnabled(true);
                    view.btnStop.setEnabled(false);
                    isStopGen = false;
                }
            }
        });

        view.btnGenerate.setEnabled(false);
        view.btnStop.setEnabled(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    private void doGeneration() throws StopGenException, InterruptedException {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            if( isStopGen) {
                throw new StopGenException();
            }
            final double val = model.getRandomNum();
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    view.listModel.addElement(val);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void stopNumGen() {
        System.out.println("Stop generation");
        isStopGen = true;
    }

    public void deleteElement() {
        System.out.println("Delete number");
        int indices[] = view.list.getSelectedIndices();

        for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
            final int index = indices[indices.length - 1 - i];
            System.out.print("Index: " + index);

            double val = view.listModel.get(index);
            System.out.println(", Deleted val: " + val);
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                    view.listModel.remove(index);
                }
            });
        }
    }

}

public class RandomNumberModel {
    public double getRandomNum() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(500);
        return Math.random();
    }
}
```

Comment: For reference, several complete examples may be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20SwingWorker).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. AFAIK and according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread):

   > all user interface components should be created and **accessed** only from the AWT event dispatch thread.

   including `view.list.getSelectedIndices()` in the `deleteElement()` method. The good news is that the `actionPerformed` event handler (which calls `deleteElement()`) is already runned by this thread so it's fine but you could get rid of the `EventQueue.invokeLater` and call `view.listModel.remove(index)` directly there.
2. The index/indices manipulation is not so convenient in the `deleteElement()` method:

   ```
   final int index = indices[indices.length - 1 - i];
   ```

   It took a while to figure out what it is doing and this is needed becase removing an element from a list shifts the indexes of elements after the removed one so you have to remove them in reversed order.

   I'd simply reverse the array and use a foreach loop:

   ```
   ArrayUtils.reverse(indices);
   for (final int elementIndex: indices) {
       view.listModel.remove(elementIndex);
   }
   ```

   `ArrayUtils` is from [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/lang/). (It's [open-source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/lang/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.java?view=markup) so you can copy-paste that method to your code if you don't want to include a library only for one helper method.)

Comment: @palacsint-Point 1: So the fact that actionPerformed is in EDT, then the code in that method that launches the thread, means the thread is in the EDT, thus requests for deleteElement(), etc are in EDT?

Comment: @drg: Every method which is called by `actionPerformed` is in EDT. You can print the current thread name with `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName())`.

Comment: @palacsint-You suggested `indices=view.list.getSelectedIndices()` in general would be  issued inside `invokeLater()`, however, I'd have to declare an instance variable to do that(!). I couldn't declare a final local variable as it can't be assigned to, and I need `indices` after `invokeLater()` I guess I could move the code that requires `indices` inside the `invokeLater()`. Any ideas on the best way to go about that?

Comment: @drg: If I understand correctly I probably would use a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` field for that which is thread-safe.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is well structured, and nice to read. This is a good thing.

You appear, from what I can see, to be using the appropriate threads for doing swing, and non-swing work. This is good.

There are a few thread-safe issues I can see:

- **Daemon Threads** - where possible, you [should use Daemon threads for background tasks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29). This makes the JVM shutdown easier, and is good practice for those times when you are not in a Swing environment (which does a 'hard' shutdown).

  ```
  thread.setDaemon(true);
  thread.start();
  ```
- There is a possible race condition in the action-listener... there could conceptually be multiple action events queued up for the `view.btnGenerate`. These actions could be queued **before** the button is disabled. This would result in you having two generator threads running at once. I would recommend something like:

  ```
  private final AtomicBoolean generatorRunning = new AtomicBoolean(false);
  ```

  then, in your `startNumGen` thread I would have:

  ```
  if (!generatorRunning.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
      // already running....
      return false;
  }
  ```

  this will gate the method explicitly... only one thread can start the generator (until it is stopped), and a thread can only start one of them (in case there are multiple queued events)...
- additionally, I would replace the `volatile isStopGen` with this `generatorRunning` AtomicBoolean. Volatile is a complicated concept, and the AtomicBoolean does the same thing, but with better semantics....

  you would replace the volatile `isStopGen` setting in the finally block with:

  ```
         finally {
              view.btnGenerate.setEnabled(true);
              view.btnStop.setEnabled(false);
              generatorRunning.set(false);
          }
  ```

  speaking of these semantics, you should check the `generatorRunning.get()` after the sleep, and before the set, rather than before the sleep. You have the risk here that you stop the generator, and then it still generates a value half a second later.... Your code could look like:

  ```
  private void doGeneration() throws StopGenException, InterruptedException {
      for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
          final double val = model.getRandomNum();

          // check after sleep... 
          if( !generatorRunning.get()) {
              throw new StopGenException();
          }
          EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  // potential double-check in a slow-to-schedule thread....
                  if (generatorRunning.get()) {
                      view.listModel.addElement(val);
                  }
              }
          });
      }
   }
  ```

Comment: As I understand, since my thread is not in EDT, I **should** use invokeLater for adding to the view:                  `view.listModel.addElement(val);` however I took it out and it runs fine.

Comment: @drg ... yes, you should use invokeLater... I am just suggesting you check the atomic-boolean in that invokeLater thread as well.

Comment: @rolfl-re: daemon threads. I believe the idea you are suggesting is that if my long running process (make it a daemon thread) is the only thing left and the program ends, it should discontinue the long thread?

Comment: @drg exactly.... if it is not daemon, and, if your program does not somehow explicitly stop it, then your program will not exit.... (unless you do a *hard* exit like `System.exit(...)`... which is ugly)

Comment: @rolfl-trying to see if I understand...would your (can't figure out how to get code in block) `if (!generatorRunning.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
    // already running....
    return false;
}` be equivalent to:`if( generatorRunning.get())
   return;
  else
   generatorRunning.set(true);`

Comment: You say: "you should check the generatorRunning.get() after the sleep, and before the set, rather than before the sleep. You have the risk here that you stop the generator, and then it still generates a value half a second later". I see the point completely. But wouldn't you want (at least in this case) to check **before** as well-to stop it from going into sleep if not needed

Comment: About the generatorRunning - yes, it is logically similar to your suggestion, except it is [atomic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html) which makes it thread-safe

Comment: About the *check after the sleep* - sleep, and the random get, are both cheap operations. What you want to avoid is the visual inconsistency if a user ***sees*** things change after pressing 'stop'. If you want to, you can check before the sleep as well, but the most critical thing is to check before updating the screen